# Predict pi.ub upper prediction interval in a meta-regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict, metafor

I have created a meta-regression:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg

res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ ablat, data=dat)
res
```

I get the following output:

```
Model Results:

         estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub      
intrcpt    0.2515  0.2491   1.0095  0.3127  -0.2368   0.7397      
ablat     -0.0291  0.0072  -4.0444  <.0001  -0.0432  -0.0150  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How can I estimate what the upper 95% prediction interval (pi.ub), when yi = 1?

Thank you.
I can predict yi for a given vi, or vi for a given yi as well as construct a plot of the prediction intervals using functions from the metafor package. However, I do not know of a way to calculate the upper 95% prediction band for a given yi.